# Is it possible to have multiple CNAME records for www?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, www

As far as I know, it is possible to have multiple A records for one host - GitHub Pages for apex domain is an example:

185.199.108.153

185.199.109.153

185.199.110.153

185.199.111.153

It is done for load balancing, Geo DNS purposes, etc.

So, what about several CNAME records for www? I have seen the setup for one domain recently that looked something like this:

www  CNAME whispering-willow-5678.herokudns.com.

www  CNAME autumn-sunset-1495.herokudns.com.

and it somehow managed to work via www.

My questions relate to the CNAME record particularly.

1. Are these CNAME records queried in turn?
2. Is it possible to have the configuration (with multiple CNAME) this way or is it a blunder?
3. Can such configuration be used for load balancing purposes or something?

Comment: in my point of View it liad balance random, as 1/4 queries going to one of 4 servers

Answer (score -2):

From a DNS zone perspective  it is valid syntax for most record types to have multiple identical resource records with the same name and type that only differ in their value.
That is not only valid syntax for `A` and `AAAA`  records, but also commonly seen with `NS` and `MX` records.

```
example.com. IN NS ns1.example.com.
example.com. IN NS ns2.example.com.
```

Your example appears to be intended as  [round robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) with all the inherent limitations in how effective that will be for load balancing. (It depends on both name server software, the resolver library and the client application how multiple records get ordered and how they will be used: if only the first, alternate, random or all records in (random) order are tried)

Comment: Is it applicable to CNAME records?

Comment: Sorry for downvite, but your answer does not actually speak to cnames - and cnames are not like other resource records.